# Magento 1.9 - own js with div load doesnt show up

Tags: javascript, magento

I use this 3rd party code:

```
        <div id="ws-widget-fdbe15">
  <iframe src="//services.wheel-size.com/widget/43c0dea07eba4cefbf04a00fbf8db530/"
          width="800" height="525" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes">
  </iframe>
</div>

    <script>
      var widget = WheelSizeWidgets.create('#ws-widget-fdbe15');
      widget.registerUserLinks({
      afterRim: {
        href: 'http://www.com/index.php/{{ rim_diameter }}-tuumaa/{{ bolt_pattern }}-{{ rim_diameter }}.html'.replace(/(\d)\.(?=\d)/g, '$1,'),
        text: ' {{ rim_diameter }}"',
        title: '{{ bolt_pattern }}'
      },
      afterTire: {
        href: 'http://www.com/index.php//{{ rim_diameter }}/{{ tire_width }}-{{ tire_aspect_ratio }}-{{ rim_diameter }}.html'.replace(/(\d)\.(?=\d)/g, '$1,'),
        text: ' {{ tire }}"',
        title: '{{ tire }}'
      }
    });

    </script>
```

And im tryed to make this show example, lets say in left nav.
I tryed many different solutions.

- Added js src line in magentos addmin, in design tab where you can add your own codes, and in source, seems like that file is loaded. And that script line in other codes to load in pageload, and seems like it is in place when looking the frontpage source code.

Then i tryed to add `<div id="ws-widget-43c0de"></div>` in leftnavigation files where the menu is loaded. But, NEVER shows anything.

I also tryed to copy all that code straight in the leftnav file, nothing results.

You can try that code in your own server,. just like that and it works perfectly.

I cleared cache everytime.

What is the proper way to make this working in magento?

Comment: And, i also added own folder in template folder called "omaphp". There is file "vannetesti.phtml" wich contains that full php code what is in first post.
Then maded in cms page this: "{{block type="core/template" name="omaphp" template="omaphp/vannetesti.phtml"}}". The source code in that cms page shows that file is loaded, but its not show anything in page ??

Comment: Updated post.
Using iframe, working nice. BUT. Those links are not showing in magento. In blank test page works nice.
Is that iframe now problem with magento when printin urls?